# How to parseInt octets out from an I.P address, store as int variables then return using a presupplied driver method

Tags: java, arrays, split, return, parseint

I'm struggling a bit here. I need to take an I.P address supplied as a string and store as a dotted decimal. split it into its 4 octets that need to be stored as int variables. Which I believe I've done here in its constructor and then using a presupplied driver method return each octet. I can't figure out how to access and send them in the "getOctet" method.
Heres the class file:

```
public class IpAddress
{
   private String dottedDecimal;
   private int firstOctet;
   private int secondOctet;
   private int thirdOctet;
   private int fourthOctet;



    //**************************************************************

    public IpAddress()
    { } // end 0 parameter constructor

    //*************************************************

    public IpAddress(String d)
    {
        this.dottedDecimal = d;
        
        String[] ipArr = dottedDecimal.split("\\.");
        this.firstOctet = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[0]);
        this.secondOctet = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[1]);
        this.thirdOctet = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[2]);
        this.fourthOctet = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[3]);

        
    } // end 1 parameter constructor

    //************************************************************



    public String getDottedDecimal()
    {
        return this.dottedDecimal;
    }
    
    //********************************************************

    public String getOctet(int n)
    {
     
    }
```

Here is the driver method I have to use unchanged:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  
    IpAddress ip = new IpAddress("216.27.6.136");
  
    System.out.println(ip.getDottedDecimal());
  
    System.out.println(ip.getOctet(4));
  
    System.out.println(ip.getOctet(1));
  
    System.out.println(ip.getOctet(3));
  
    System.out.println(ip.getOctet(2));
  
  } // end main
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I think I have to use an array, which I've tried but I don't exactly know how to use, Arrays are technically the next module we're learning after this assignment so I haven't actually learned how to use them yet

Answer (score 0):

I did this for getOctet method and it seems to work.
It isn't exactly elegant but it worked

```
public int getOctet(int n)
{

    int arr[] = new int[5];
    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1]= this.firstOctet;    
    arr[2]= this.secondOctet;    
    arr[3]= this.thirdOctet;    
    arr[4]= this.fourthOctet; 
    return arr[n];
} // end getOctet
```

Comment: Why not use the first element rather than setting it to zero?

Comment: I would have used the first element [0] but I wasn't allowed to alter the driver at all, and they used getOctet(1) to get first object. Should I have used (n-1) to get the firstOctet stored in the 0 position?

Comment: Yes. Java arrays start at zero, as does much of the java libraries.

Comment: You could simply say `addrBytes[n-1]`.